# Spring Eureka LoadBalanced RestTemplate when not connected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, load-balancing, netflix-eureka

Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When my Spring Boot application is registered with Eureka, I can define a `RestTemplate` bean like this:

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
  return new RestTemplate();
}
```

And in my services I can make requests to other services using their registered `spring.application.name`:

```
restTemplate.getForEntity("http://application1/test", String.class);
```

How do I define where `http://application1/` is located with Eureka disabled?

```
eureka.client.enabled=false
```

Current Implementation test:

```
@Configuration
public class RibbonConfig {

  @Bean
  public ServerList<Server> serverServerList() {
    return new ConfigurationBasedServerList();
  }
}

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
  @Bean
  @LoadBalanced
  public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
  }
}

@Component
public class TestService implements CommandLineRunner {
  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://application1/test", String.class);

    System.out.println(responseEntity);
  }
}

@RibbonClient(value = "application1", configuration = RibbonConfig.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo5Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Demo5Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

bootstrap.yml

```
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false

application1:
  ribbon:
    list-of-servers: http://localhost:8081/
```

Comment: Why don't you use feign client instead of RestTemplate

Answer (score 0):

you can define a new RibbonClient configuration for your service this way:

```
@Configuration
@RibbonClient(name = "application1", configuration = Application1RibbonClientConfiguration.class)
public class Application {
...
}

class Application1RibbonClientConfiguration{
    @Bean
    public ServerList<Server> ribbonServerList() {
        return new ConfigurationBasedServerList(); 
    }
}
```

you can skip all the configuration above if you don't have eureka on classPath

next in your properties file you can list all the servers location like this:

```
application1.ribbon.listOfServers=..,..,..
```

Comment: I'm getting a NPE. Looks like `IClientConfig` hasn't been initialized? I've added everything I have so far.

Comment: can you add the exception stack to your post?